# Отсутствует /sys/class/backlight

Tags: linux, kernel

В моей текущей системе (`linux` **3.16.6**) отсутствует содержимое директории */sys/class/backlight*.  Я собирался использовать это содержимое для того, чтобы отображать текущую яркость дисплея в приглашении командной строки и чтобы влиять на эту яркость, но там ничего нет.
При этом если я загружаю другую систему, `openSUSE`, там эта директория заполнена. То есть очевидно разница в загружаемых модулях (на самом деле, и в версии ядра, которое в SUSE 3.17.*). В списке загруженных модулей в openSUSE *нет* `backlight`, а /sys/class/backlight полон. В списке `linux` (называю так, потому что по сути загружается только ядро) этот модуль есть, но при этом директория пуста.
При этом среди самих модулей openSUSE на 3-4 модуля в папке */lib/modules/$(uname -r)/drivers/video/backlight/* - больше, нежели в аналогичной папке второй используемой системы. Хотя я не понимаю, почему модуль backlight отсутствует в списке загруженных в openSUSE, хотя его функционал работает.

Вопрос. **Какие варианты разобраться в причинах отсутствия функционала backlight и\или добавить его без перекомпиляции ядра у меня есть?**

Просто скопировать "добавочные" модули из openSUSE во вторую систему - понятное дело, не катит. Ну, на самом деле, я попробовал...

PS Некоторые из предлагаемых в решениях этой проблемы способы я уже пробовал. Добавлял в опции загрузки *acpi_backlight=vendor*/*legacy*, например. Не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема, насколько я понимаю, не в «остутствии псевдо-каталога псевдо-файловой системы», а в незнании используемой вами версией программы *linux* о том, как быть с устройством подсветки вашего *чипсета*.

самый логичный, с моей точки зрения, выход: поставить более новую версию программы (как в протестированном вами дистрибутиве *opensuse*, или новее).

Comment: Этот вариант самый очевидный, но и самый сложный для исполнения, потому что более новая версия ядра не обязательно доступна в реализации Tiny Core. Кроме того, к той, что имелась, я применял патчи, так что процесс апгрейда ядра в этом случае будет достаточно трудоёмок.

Comment: То есть просто каким-то образом обновить или добавить сами модули я не могу?

Comment: технически — можете: «примените патчи». собственно, весь процесс разработки любой программы (с точки зрения программиста) — это «применение патчей».

Comment: Я имею в виду горячее добавление модулей, без пересборки ядра. Просто добавить файл модуля в /lib/modules я не могу?

Comment: можете. если модуль собран для вашей версии программы.

Comment: скажем так: собрать новую версию программы *linux* — **гораздо** проще, чем бэкпортировать какую-то отсутствующую в текущей версии функциональность.

Comment: Понятно... еще в теории я могу найти пакет с заголовками для конкретно этой версии и исходники модуля и собрать... но я даже толком не знаю, какой модуль собирать-то. Придется поэкспериментировать, прежде чем пересобирать ядро.